# Subprocess PID on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

How do I get the PID of a subprocess opened with `shell = True` on a Windows OS?
I am trying to run several commands this way using a for loop, taking them in as arguments - the running of them works fine.
However, the PID returned from `procName.pid` does not match with the tasklist PID.
For example:

```
pidDict = {}
for proc in argsPassed:
    p = subprocess.Popen(proc, shell=True)
    pidDict[proc] = p.pid
```

Comparing `pidDict` to the PIDs of my processes in tasklist do not match, not even close. I need to keep track of these for killing them later on.
Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True`?

Comment: I need to open each of the processes in their own shell, and they will interact with each other. I then need to be able to kill one, two, or all of these processes - using the PID is the most direct way I could of doing this.

Comment: Since the shell is what is actually running the processes, I doubt you can get the pid.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this in a hacky way, but this will only work if you know there will be no other processes opened with the same image name while the script is running. In my case this was okay because I was looking for `q.exe` processes, and it was only on my local machine. The code that works:

```
pidDict = {}
for proc in argsPassed:
     subprocess.Popen(proc, shell=True)
     time.sleep(1)
     p_list = subprocess.Popen(‘tasklist.exe /fo csv’, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

     for p in csv.DictReader(p_list.stdout):
          if (p[‘Image Name’] == ‘q.exe’) and (p[‘PID’] not in pidDict.values()):
              pidDict[i] = p[‘PID’]
```